# How to create a loop

Tags: r, loops, statistics

Can you explain the structure/idea of loop in R-Code? I don't know where to start with this homework problem. I was able to create the exponential distribution I needed with

```
> rexp(n=200, rate=0.5)
```

but now I need to create 2,000 samples of this rexp and calculate the mean of each sample. Then I need to calculate the mean and variance of the 2,000 sample means. I know how to find the mean and variance of a simple distribution (ex: `mean(rexp)` and `var(rexp)`), so my main issue is understanding this concept of a loop and putting it into action.

So I started with entering:

```
> rexp(n=200,rate=0.5)
```

Then I named this exponential distribution:

```
> exdi = rexp(n=200,rate=0.5)
```

Based off of an example dealing with sums, I entered

```
>y.exdi=vector(length=2000)
>for(i in 1:2000){y.exdi[ i ]=mean(exdi)}
```

The R Workspace gave no response to this, so I named the function and tried this:

```
>Twothou = for(i in 1:2000){y.exdi[ i ]=mean(exdi)}
>mean(Twothou)
```

But then I got this error message:

```
[1] NA
Warning message:
In mean.default(Twothou) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

What should I do differently?

Answer (score 6):

You've just created a really nice vector of 2000 elements of the same value - in the means of the mean of your sample brewed for exponential distribution only once. See by checking `y.exdi` in your console.

If you want to use a loop for this solution, you should create new and new samples in each iteration. You may do that easily with e.g. `sapply` (wrapper around the `for` loop) applied to `1:2000`:

```
sapply(1:2000, function(x) mean(rexp(n = 200, rate = 0.5)))
```

Or rather directly calling e.g. `replicate` (that was intended to be used for such cases):

```
replicate(2000, mean(rexp(n = 200, rate = 0.5)))
```

Comment: +1 for `replicate`. I would not recommend the `sapply` approach at all since writing a function that ignores its argument is ugly.

Comment: @flodel: ...ignoring the fact that `replicate` wraps `sapply`. :)

Answer (score 3):

I think you should put the random number generator `rexp` **inside** your `for` loop:

```
y.exdi=vector(length=2000)
for(i in 1:2000){
    y.exdi[ i ]=mean(rexp(n=200,rate=0.5))
}
```

Otherwise, for each `i` you just calculate the mean of a fixed vector defined outside the loop, instead of new ones generated each time the index `i` increases. Having that codes above, you can calculate the mean using `mean(y.exdi)`, which gives you the average of the 2000 "averages".

Answer (score 2):

You need to create your sample distribution *within* the loop.  Try this:

```
> set.seed(1)
> y.exdi=vector(length=2000)
> for(i in 1:2000){
+ exdi = rexp(n=200,rate=0.5)
+ y.exdi[ i ]=mean(exdi)
+ }
> mean(y.exdi)
[1] 2.001149
> var(y.exdi)
[1] 0.01987367
```

Comment: If your answer is not much different than someone's who answered even one second faster than you did, please consider deleting yours.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have to generate the sample 2000 times, so sample generation has to be in the loop.

```
set.seed(1)
y.exdi <- vector(length=2000, "numeric")
for (i in 1:2000)
{
    y.exdi[i] <- mean(rexp(200, 0.5))
}
```

The problem is also with the command

```
   exdi = rexp(n=200,rate=0.5)
```

in which you are actually assigning to `exdi` a numeric vector of 200 exponentially distributed randomly generated values, it does not define a function. Actually, you don't need to redefine a function, you can just call `rexp` every time.

R also provides shortcuts for these type of things. You can get 2000 means with a one-liner

```
sapply(1:2000, function(x) { mean(rexp(200, 0.5)) })
```

Comment: If your answer is not much different than someone's who answered even one second faster than you did, please consider deleting yours.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two solutions. The first does not need to create the sample twice but the anonymous function and its return of a list is odd. The second is cleaner, you do get the column names but you no longer have the mean tied to the variance of the same sample.

```
library(plyr)

ldply(1:2000, function(x) {d <- rexp(n = 200, rate = 0.5); c(mean(d), var(d))})

ddply(data.frame(x = 1:2000), .(x), summarize, 
  mean = mean(rexp(n = 200, rate = 0.5)), var = var(rexp(n = 200, rate = 0.5)))
```

Your solution puts the value in the y.exdi list. If you look at its contents when constructed it will be full of boolean FALSE values. After the loop you can re-inspect it and see that it has the mean as its elements. Here are two equally valid ways to complete what you were trying to do with loops with a few things cleaned up.

```
y.exdi <- NULL
for(i in 1:2000) y.exdi[i] <- mean(rexp(n = 200, rate = 0.5))

y.exdi <- vector(length = 2000, mode = "numeric")
for(i in seq(y.exdi)) y.exdi[i] <- mean(rexp(n = 200, rate = 0.5))
```